# Exponent of prime $p$ in $n!$

Tags: factorial

> For how many positive integral values of $n$ does $n!$ end with precisely $25$ zeroes?

*My work*

Number of zeroes at the end of $n!$=$25$

Using [Legendre's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_formula#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20Legendre%27s%20formula%20gives,formula%2C%20after%20Alphonse%20de%20Polignac.),

$$E_5(n!)=25$$

$$\lfloor \frac{n}{5} \rfloor+\lfloor \frac{n}{25} \rfloor +...=25.$$

How to solve this? Can you give me hint?

Comment: Have a look at [this page](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/blue/LegendresTheorem.shtml).

Comment: And an example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3223081/find-the-no-of-trailing-zeroes-of-20190/).

Comment: Variants of this question have been asked and answered on this website many times already. Please try doing a search for earlier occurences.

Comment: @Liang so did you find the minimum $n$ such that $\nu_5(n!)=\frac{n-s_5(n)}{4}=25$?

Comment: Why I am asking this ... say you found that minim $n$ then if $5 \nmid n+1$ then $\nu_5((n+1)!)=25$ too. If $5 \nmid n+2$ then $\nu_5((n+2)!)=25$ as well ... However, five consecutive numbers always contain one divisible by five. So, you will have to stop at some point.

Comment: Thank you @rtybase you solved this question without finding the numbers. answer will always be $5$.

Comment: The series $\frac n5 + \frac{n}{5^2} + \dots = \frac n 4$, so $\big\lfloor\frac n 5 \big\rfloor + \big\lfloor \frac n {5^2} \big\rfloor + \dots$ is roughly $\frac n 4$, so for this to equal $25$, $n=100$ is a good place to start looking.

Comment: Why is the downvote? Is this question bad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You solved upto this step.

$$\lfloor \frac{n}{5} \rfloor+\lfloor \frac{n}{25}\rfloor+...=25$$

First put $n$=$100$.

$$\lfloor \frac{100}{5} \rfloor+\lfloor \frac{100}{25}\rfloor+...=20+4=24$$

You need one more $0$.

Now put $n$=$105$

$$\lfloor \frac{105}{5} \rfloor+\lfloor \frac{105}{25}\rfloor+...=21+4=25$$

This continues upto $n$=$109$.

So, there are 5 such integers.